# JavaScript API for GestureRecognizer

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an small writing application for Chinese character practice, on which users has to draw the characters(Chinese characters) on screen, i need to validate the user drawing (character may have 3 to four steps and flow to draw) with the original character, how can i validate the user drawing? Is there any API available for this?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/

You can easily extend it as required for chinese characters. It is very efficient framework with high accuracy. A good start unless you want 100% accuracy.